# How Can I access Windows Service Object by Another Programme

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-services, named-pipes

I have a windows service which is creating a Named Pipe in it's service main Function. The code snippet is below:

```
void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
  DWORD status;
  DWORD specificError;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

  m_ServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler("myService", 
                                            ServiceCtrlHandler); 
  if (m_ServiceStatusHandle == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0)
  {
    return;
  }
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
  m_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
  if (!SetServiceStatus (m_ServiceStatusHandle, &m_ServiceStatus))
  {
  }

    CraeteNamedPipe();

     return;
}
```

The `CraeteNamedPipe` function creates a named pipe `\\.\pipe\1stPipe`.

I am able to successfully install and run my service on my XP machine.
Now how can I access the namedpipe `\\.\pipe\1stPipe` by using another program.

Any Code snippet or sample article will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you not only use [CreateNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150.aspx) but also [ConnectNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365146.aspx). It is also very important to set [Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365600.aspx) to the pipe (see `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter of the [CreateNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150.aspx)) to be able to communicate with the pipe created by another user (typical situation if you create pipe inside of a windows service and use outside of the service).

To connect to the pipe from the client side one can use either [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) or [CallNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365144.aspx) depend on the [type mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365605.aspx) (see also [Can you explain in more detail what's the difference between PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE/PIPE_READMODE_BYTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539914/can-you-explain-in-more-detail-whats-the-difference-between-pipe-readmode-messag/3541775#3541775)).

In the message-type pipe one uses typically [CallNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365144.aspx) or [TransactNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365790.aspx) (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365789.aspx as an example). In the byte-type pipe one uses standard read/write file operation with respect of [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467.aspx) and [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747.aspx).

Different example of using pipes you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365799.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search got me these results:

1. http://ist.marshall.edu/ist480acp/namedpipes.html
2. http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/sharedmemory/article.php/c5771

Do those help at all?

** (I only glanced at them, and have no experience with pipes)*

Comment: Nah, I tells abt creatin and methods of named pipe. But I need to know how to access a object(for now it's a NamedPipe) that is present inside a window service.